# How to write Special characters in a file using mfc application?

Tags: c++, file, visual-c++, mfc

I want to write special charaters like ô. ö‚`a¹½ˆ in a file. I am working in MFC and using UNICODE character set. While showing string in message box is working good but its not writing  the characters to the file.

Here is parts of my code:

```
CString abc=_T("hello");
CString xyz=compress(abc); //compressing value and return special characters
CStdioFile file_object(_T("abc.txt"),CFile::modeCreate|CFile::modeWrite);
file_object.WriteString(xyz);
```

Comment: What did you do that did't work? Show us the codez! :)

Comment: i am taking a CString variable say CString =_T("hello"); and compressing it which returns a value with special characters like shown above and finally i want to write that string in a text file.

Comment: with normal character is working good but when special characters starts it stop writing to the file.

Comment: How are you opening the file and writing to the file? Please edit the question the put your code there. PLEASE! I have some guesses about the type of file you are opening (text or binary), but can't say anything for sure until I see your code.

Comment: Actually my Code is large but i am trying to explain in short..
CString abc=_T("hello");
CString xyz=compress(abc);            //compressing string abc and return special characters
abc=abc+xyz;
CStdioFile file_object(_T("abc.txt"),CFile::modeCreate|CFile::modeWrite);
file_object.WriteString(abc);
file_object.Close();

Comment: it is writing only "hello" in the file.
if i use AfxMessagebox(abc); then its showing special charecters also but not writing to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `CStdioFile` class does not support Unicode characters directly. You can use this workaround (from [this CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/465194/Read-and-Write-Text-Files-in-Unicode-through-CStdi) article)

```
// Open the file with the specified encoding
FILE *fStream;
errno_t e = _tfopen_s(&fStream, _T("abc.txt"), _T("wt,ccs=UTF-8"));
if (e != 0) return; // failed..
CStdioFile f(fStream);  // open the file from this stream

f.WriteString(xyz);
f.Close();

//
// For Reading
//

// Open the file with the specified encoding
FILE *fStream;
errno_t e = _tfopen_s(&fStream, _T("abc.txt"), _T("rt,ccs=UTF-8"));
if (e != 0) return; // failed..CString sRead;
CStdioFile f(fStream);  // open the file from this stream
CString sRead;
f.ReadString(sRead);
f.Close();
```

Instead of using "UTF-8" encoding, you can also use the following encodings:

> “ccs=UNICODE” => UTF-16 (Big endian)
>    “ccs=UTF-8” => UTF-8
>    “ccs=UTF-16LE” => UTFS-16LE (Little endian)
>    “ccs=ANSI” => ANSI (default encoding of the OS)

Comment: Your Code is Working good and writing special characters in file, but when i tried to copy that data and paste to another file then some problem is comming in alignment.

Comment: @Himanshu What do you mean exactly? Text alignment is responsibility of the control that is displaying the text, and is not copied with the text.

Comment: your code is working good.
Suppose I am writing in file like this...<br/>
a 10 xœuKkÃ0<br>
b 20 xœu<br>
c 30 œkÃ0<br>
and when I open that file and again saving it then is save like this<br>
a 10 xœuKkÃ0b 20 xœuc 30 œkÃ0<br>
means it is not taking next line characters.

Comment: @Himanshu I guess the problem lies in your new-line character. Use a single `\n` for new-line.

Comment: Sir, I used '\n' but it didn't worked instead of it i used '\r\n' then its taking new-line character.

Answer (score 1):

I found one more method. It is working good...

```
CString text=_T("HelloÄ^°H©º+");
CString strFilePath=_T("C:\\try.txt");
CFile theFile(strFilePath, CFile::modeReadWrite | CFile::modeCreate);
theFile.Write( (LPCTSTR) text, text.GetLength() * sizeof(TCHAR));
theFile.Close();
```